# Vim: Geting out of insert mode. When I map alt-key combinations in insert mode, the character associated gets mapped, not the alt-key-combination

Tags: vim, utf-8, insert, alt

Background: I use alt-h j k l etc. to get out of insert mode. 
The reason to do such a thing is explained
[here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Avoid_the_escape_key).

In my XTerm this worked by default, but in gvim it doesn't.

I guess you can see the *life-threatening gravity* of this problem to me, as finding a good solution to get out of insert mode is absolutely essential to flow -- and I thought I found it for me... (edited my Formulation in response to Amandan...).

Is there a was to have gedit behave in a "alt sends escape"-kind of way?

There might be other solutions, but they seem pretty ugly:

My strategy for now was that I tried mappings (w,e,d,c,r,A and whatever) so that for instance alt-dw in insert mode would get me to normal mode and delete the word after the cursor by simple mappings like:

```
inoremap <m-d> <Esc>ld
inoremap <m-x> <Esc>lx
inoremap <m-X> <Esc>lX
inoremap <m-u> <Esc>u
inoremap <m-p> <Esc>p
```

(the l before the command corrects the placement of the cursor)

This works very well, but these mappings do not map the alt-key-combinations, but the caracters associated (in utf-8-encoding).

In the above exemple:

ä, ø, Ø, õ, ð

The problem is, that when I tap ä for exemple (I'm german, so it's right on my keyboard AND I NEED IT BADLY), vim will get out of insert mode and start a "delete"-operation. Meaning that I loose every possibility to enter an ä (or é, ê, ö, etc. all of wich are vital to me).

Is there a way to map alt-key-combinations and not the caracter associated? (This question is secondary. It's only interesting inasmuch it serves the primary one: use alt-stuff to get out of insert mode)

Other stuff that I tried or checked:

-- I did

```
set termencoding=ascii
```

but it didn't have any effect (in gvim-gui - when I run it in a terminal, it has an effect, but it's not there that I need it).

-- My enoding options are set way before my mappings so it is not a parsing problem.

-- I tried

```
unmap <M-J>
inoremap <M-J> <Nop>
```

No effect.

Comment: "getting out of insert mode is one of the big problems in vi"? I'd say that is a highly subjective statement, one that most long-time users would dispute. Using Esc where it is on modern keyboards might be an issue, but most people will either get used to it or rebind some other key for it (whether in Vim or in OS). I have never heard of another user doing what that page is describing, and it is a horrible hack that only works because of how a certain class of terminals work. In gVim there is no terminal, thus the hack can't work. Fighting against the Vim way is usually not productive.

Comment: I really don't think to be fighting against vim... I mean this IS something that worked in terminals right? I admit that my preference is subjective, but you will agree that the way you find to get out of insert is an important issue that you have to figure out for flow. You say yourself that Esc is unsatisfactory. I did simply rebind the key and it works. I would just be happier to continue using directly alt-command in insert mode to get out of it. Got used to it and it continues to seem to me like the most productive way. But I agree that massive remapping would be ugly and it would be a th

Comment: It worked in terminals by accident, not by design. It's like saying it is okay to enter through a broken window, and regarding lack of broken windows in neighbouring buildings as a feature loss. And I said that Esc *might* be unsatisfactory (to some people): I actually have what is usually considered a more convenient keybind (`kj`), but I keep using Esc. Anyway, if it works for you, it's all good.

Comment: Yea. I know i'm actually asking sort of a downgrade, but well... it worked really well.